# Вставка в таблицу заданное количество строк

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Возникла потребность вставить в таблицу N-ое количество строк. Вставляемые данные генерируется встроенными в T-SQL функциями. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно модифицировать следующий запрос что бы он вставил в таблицу нужное количество строк?

INSERT INTO TableName 
SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE()

Интересует, есть ли возможность сделать это, без использования циклов.

Comment: Может быть цикл?

Comment: Интересует возможность без использования цикла. Про WHILE %условие% я слышал, спасибо.

Comment: а рядышком нет таблицы, содержащей N или больше строк?

Comment: Хм... Можно конечно использовать "левую" таблицу и сделать что то вроде этого: 
INSERT INTO TableName1 SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE() FROM (SELECT TOP n * FROM TableName2). Но мне кажется это еще хуже чем использовать цикл.

Comment: а чем не угодил `INSERT INTO TableName1 SELECT TOP N NEWID(), GETDATE() FROM TableName2`? подзапрос там не нужен

Comment: забыл уточнить мне нужно это для написания процедуры которая по переданному N будет производить вставку. Поэтому может возникнуть ситуация что N будет такое, что у меня не окажется таблицы с таким количество хранящихся в ней строк. Но Ваша идея хорошая, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если рядом есть таблица подходящего размера - `INSERT INTO TableName1 SELECT TOP N NEWID(), GETDATE() FROM TableName2`

Поскольку это хранимая процедура и `N` будет параметром - используем `EXECUTE`:

`DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(max)='INSERT INTO TableName1 SELECT TOP '+CAST(@N AS VARCHAR(MAX))+' NEWID(), GETDATE() FROM TableName2'
EXECUTE(@Qry)`

2. Используем рекурсивную CTE:

   `;WITH cte AS
   (SELECT 1 t
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t+1 t FROM cte
   WHERE t<@N)
   INSERT INTO TableName1
   SELECT NEWID(), GETDATE() FROM cte OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)`

CTE работает раз в 10 дольше.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так вставляется сразу несколько строк

```
insert into tablename (id,name) values(1,'rusic'),(2,'rusic2'),(3,'rusic3');
```

Меняем под себя и все

Comment: Минус не проблема, но обоснования? У меня рабочий вариант инъекция вставит три строки, можно id не указывать и вставятся  автоназначенные, это только пример. Я так понимаю задача стояла вставить три значения подряд, мой вариант работает, вместо имени вставляем GETDATE()

Comment: Задача вставлять N. Например, миллион. Про три речи в вопросе не было.

Comment: Да, не дочитался, принято.